# Energy spectrum of photoneutrons

Tags: kinematics, radiation, neutrons

In "Radiation Detection and Measurement" Knoll considers the production of neutrons by a ($\gamma$, n) reaction such as

\begin{align}
\gamma + \ ^{2}_{1}\text{H} \rightarrow \ ^{1}_{1}\text{H} + n
&& Q=-2.22\text{ MeV}
\end{align}

and gives the following formula, without proof or source, for the neutron (kinetic) energy:

$$
E_n \approx \frac{M}{M+m}(E_\gamma + Q) + E_\gamma\frac{\sqrt{(2mM)(m+M)(E_\gamma+Q)}}{(m+M)^2}\cos(\theta)
$$

where $M,m$ are the target and neutron mass-energy; $E_\gamma$ the photon energy and $\theta$ the angle between the photon and neutron momenta.

I have been trying to derive this formula in both relativistic and classical kinematics but I couldn't produce this result. In particular is not clear to me what kind of approximation can be used (notice the $\approx$ sign) in this situation.

I can only think that the energy gained by the target is going to be small compared to the Q-value if the photon it not extremely energetic, so
$$
\frac{(E_\gamma+Q)^2}{2M} /Q
$$

could be used to expand $E_n$ in a series.

Do you have any suggestion or source?